# How make worked array in Groovy (Scriptrunner) ? (jira/workflow/post-function)

Tags: groovy, jira

Please tell me how I can make my code work with a Groovy array (scriptrunner)
I wrote the code and it only works when getting a specific element (string)

I've tried for the 100th time to make a loop, but without success...

There is A little of information on this topic, I am drowning in guesses about what is going wrong..

My goal :
Check an array containing linked issues in jira for their issue type.

For example, if the array contains a linked task with type "bug" then return true

My code:

```
//arrLinkedIssue = issue.getLinkedIssues() //[TENDER-25941, ATL-2925] Result type:ArrayList


def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.issueManager 

issue = issueManager.getIssueObject('TENDER-25941')
issType = issue.get("issuetype").name

if (issType in 'Bug'){
  return issType
}
```

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple groovy with some mocks for demo purposes:

```
def arrLinkedIssue = ['TENDER-25941', 'ATL-2925']
def mockIssueManagerContent = ['TENDER-25941':[ issuetype:[ name:'Bug' ] ], 'ATL-2925':[ issuetype:[ name:'Feature' ] ]]

//def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.issueManager 
def issueManager = [ getIssueObject:{ mockIssueManagerContent[ it ] } ] // mock issueManager

boolean isBugged = arrLinkedIssue.any{ 'Bug' == issueManager.getIssueObject( it )?.issuetype?.name }

assert isBugged
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, it would work well if it were always these specific tasks, but you can’t do without a loop, because the values ​​​​will constantly change.

Comment: there's a loop in my answer of course

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time, I was finally able to figure it out. Hope this helps someone

```
arrLinkedIssue = issue.getLinkedIssues() //[TENDER-25941, ATL-2925] Result type:ArrayList

issLi = []
def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.issueManager

for(i in arrLinkedIssue) {

issueLinkKey = issueManager.getIssueObject(i.toString())
issType = issueLinkKey.get("issuetype").name
issLi.add(issType)
} 
//return issLi [Bug, Task]

if('Bug' in issLi){
return false // The task contains a linked task with the task type "Bug" -> Post-function not start!
}
else{ //The task does not have a link task with the task type "Bug" or there is no link at all (null) -> Post-function is launched!

return true
}
```